# toggling (show/hide) one background out of a two-background div, css jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I have a 2-background div arrangement, `A` is always to be shown within the element and `B` is toggled according its buttonc control click.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .container{
  url(B.png) 10px 10px no-repeat, 
   url(A.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,  
  }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.container').on('click', function(){

     //$(this).css("background","A.png")? add/removeClass?
  });
```

How Can I get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with `background-size` to show/hide one of the background-image:

```js
$('.container').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background-image: 
  url(https://lorempixel.com/300/200/), 
  url(https://lorempixel.com/350/200/);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hide {
  background-size: 0 0, cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I am curious, if background-size is 0, why one of them still show up? I thought both of them will disappear.

Comment: same question mate. figure out the top background is a `checked icon`.

Comment: @Sphinx we have multiple background, for one it's 0 and the other it's cover ;)

Comment: @joe we have multiple background, so two different sizes .. one is 0 0 and the other cover ;)

Comment: `B -> 0 0`  & `A -> cover` got it.

Comment: @joe yes :) easy without extra markup or complicate code ;)

Comment: [Using multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds); so powerful... we need to keep studying...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like show one image as default background, then toggle the other one.

My idea:

1. Create another css class name = `extra-background`, put Image A into .container, then put Image B into .extra-background.
2. When click, toggleClass('extra-background')

```js
$('.container').on('click', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("extra-background");
});
```

```css
.container{
 background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f1/Vue.png/215px-Vue.png") #00D no-repeat fixed;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}

.extra-background{
 background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c9/VueCinemas.svg/1200px-VueCinemas.svg.png") #00D no-repeat fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">Test</div>
```